# Plug.Conn.Unfetched does not implement the Access behaviour

Tags: struct, runtime-error, elixir, phoenix-framework

From the code below, when I call `conn.params["geo"]`, I get the following error:

```
test/plugs/geoip_test.exs:4
 ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Plug.Conn.Unfetched.fetch/2 is undefined  (Plug.Conn.Unfetched does not implement the Access behaviour)
 stacktrace:
   (plug) Plug.Conn.Unfetched.fetch(%{:__struct__ => Plug.Conn.Unfetched, :aspect => :params, "geo" => "Mountain View, US", "ip" => "8.8.8.8"}, "geo")
```

...

```
defmodule AgilePulse.Plugs.GeoIPTest do
  use AgilePulse.ConnCase

  test "returns Mountain View for 8.8.8.8" do
    conn = build_conn
    params = Map.put(conn.params, "ip", "8.8.8.8")
    conn = Map.put(conn, :params, params) |> AgilePulse.Plugs.GeoIP.call(%{})

    assert conn.params["geo"] == "Mountain View, US"
  end

end

defmodule AgilePulse.Plugs.GeoIP do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(%Plug.Conn{params: %{"ip" => ip}} = conn, _opts) do
    geo = set_geo(ip)
    params = Map.put(conn.params, "geo", geo)
    Map.put(conn, :params, params)
  end

  def call(conn, _opts), do: conn

  ...

end
```

Could someone enlighten me on why this is failing and what the appropriate solution is? TY!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Change this:

```
params = Map.put(conn.params, "ip", "8.8.8.8")
```

To:

```
params = %{"ip": "8.8.8.8"}
```

Explanation: `Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn/0` returns a `Conn` with `params` set to `%Plug.Conn.Unfetched{}`. By using `Map.put` on that, you don't reset the value of `__struct__`, but only add a new key:

```
%Plug.Conn{ ...,
 params: %{:__struct__ => Plug.Conn.Unfetched, :aspect => :params,
   "ip" => "8.8.8.8"}, ... }
```

When you call `params["geo"]` later, Elixir sees that `params` is a struct, and tries to call the `fetch/2` function on the struct's module, which doesn't exist. To reset `params` to a normal map (so that Elixir calls `Map.get` when you use the square bracket syntax), you can just do `params = %{"ip": "8.8.8.8"}`.

Comment: nice! so in my particular case, in order to get the test to pass, had to use params = %{"ip" => "8.8.8.8"}. but worked out thanks to you!